# Git push over webdav hangs

Tags: git, webdav, git-push

Since last night, pushing to my own server (which I've been using for two years) halts without error. I'm stumped as to what's causing this. There seems to be no network activity when it hangs, and the process isn't doing much either (on both sides, local & remote). There's plenty of space left on the server so that isn't it either.

Anyone know how I begin to debug this?

Comment: It might be probably a network issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First run with -v | --verbose to see if you get any more output.

Second look on the far end with `sudo netstat -anp | grep 80` - assuming you are running on port 80 - or you can look for a process name instead of the port in the grep. If you see nothing, you are not connecting.

Another way to check is to look locally with `sudo netstat -anp | grep 80` and see if you are stuck in SYN SENT - if so, you have network issues, if it says CONNECTED you have progressed further.

You should also look in your http logs to see if you see anything in there on your server. But most likely this is a network or dns issue.

Comment: Thanks! Turns out I'm stuck in "SYN SENT"

Comment: I never managed to resolve the issue, but then my connection coincidentally went down a few hours for maintenance (which I guess involved a lot of rebooting and deleting of caches) after which everything worked just fine. Your hints helped me figure out it wasn't an issue on my side though, so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check the logs of your server. As you are using webdav, you should especially check the apache logs (if you are using apache). If you find anything strange, you have a clue what might cause the problem.

Can you connect to your server with something else? If you can't even do a ping, you know that your server/the network is down.